# Line Chart won't cover 100% of Horizontal Axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a graph that won't cover the full chart area Horizontally

Here is the sample data that is used to achieve the graph

[
[
"2021-07-08",
53,
0,
53,
0,
38,
0
],
[
"2021-07-09",
11,
26,
27,
98,
20,
47
],
[
"2021-07-10",
80,
42,
14,
35,
20,
13
],
[
"2021-07-11",
16,
12,
17,
25,
47,
79
],
[
"2021-07-12",
41,
12,
10,
12,
64,
40
],
[
"2021-07-13",
32,
84,
30,
72,
19,
18
],
[
"2021-07-14",
12,
50,
44,
85,
25,
11
],
[
"2021-07-15",
43,
60,
26,
74,
88,
30
]
]

My options are

```
var options = {
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                chartArea:{left:20, right:0, top:0,width:'100%',height:'75%'}
        };
```

See attached image with result [image]

How do I make the Horizontal axis cover the whole chart?

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data? are there blank rows following the last row for 2021-07-15?

Comment: doubt this is the issue but wouldn't hurt to add the following options --> `width:'100%', height:'100%'` -- these exist not only for the `chartArea` but the chart overall -- (e.g. `{legend: {position: 'bottom'}, chartArea:{left:20, right:0, top:0, width:'100%', height:'75%'}, width:'100%', height:'100%'}`)

Comment: There is no blank data at the end, and adding the width and height params still didn't change the graph

Comment: I'm not able to re-produce the issue, will you please share all of the code? see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/rcm0xsbp/2/)...